# JSON and AJAX, can't load, need JSONP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```
function getJson(){
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("Success.");   
            //$('#bigdiv').append(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        alert( jqXHR.status );
    }

  });
}

$("#start").click(function(){
  alert("check0");
  getJson();
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjvwPL

I'm stuck here, why can't I retrive data from that URL?

Comment: I hope that is just test data. It seems to contain passwords and maybe medical information?

Comment: nah, thats just random generated info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codepen as posted will not work (at least in Chrome) because codepen uses https but the resource requested is http. But that aside, your real problem is probably that it's a cross-domain request and your server is not allowing this.

> `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://zadanie.laboratorium.ee/users.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 502.`

You probably need headers like this on the server side for this to work:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://calling-website.com
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; frame-ancestors https://calling-website.com
```

You might need more than that. You can find a lot more information in the [Google Developer Docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/).

Answer (score 0):

It's a cross-protocol problem.

Codepen is on an `https://` url, so the ajax and iframe calls try to use that protocol --  but your server doesn't have https configured so returns a "502 Bad Gateway" error.  As currently configured your data is only available at the plain http://zadanie.laboratorium.ee/users.json URL.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas: Check out [cross origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Also, when using CodePen make sure your call isn't blocked due to something like non-HTTPS url.